# Server 2012 Group Policy Script

Tags: group-policy

What is the best way through Group Policy to make a registry file run on logon for computers in a domain?

I'm testing on a Windows Server 2012, with Windows 8 clients.

I have created a Group Policy applied to a 'Computers' folder of which the computers are in, but the .reg file is not running on sign in.

Comment: Computers don't sign in. If you want to use a script then a startup script will run when the computer starts. A logon script will run when a user logs on. Computer settings need to be configured in a GP linked to the computer OU. User settings need to be configured in a GP linked to the user OU. If you want to use GPP then configure GPP under Computer Configuration if you want to run it for the computer or configure it under User Configuration if you want it to run for the user.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use Group Policy Preferences.

There are two places for these settings:

`Computer Config\Preferences\Windows Settings\Registry`

and

`User Config\Preferences\Windows Settings\Registry`

You can craft new registry settings for the recipients of this Group Policy in there.

You can create HKLM and HKCU, etc., registry keys in either the User or Computer configuration areas.  It's basically just a matter of whether you want the registry settings to apply as the computer logs on (e.g. during bootup) or if you want the registry settings to apply every time a user logs on.

Comment: Group Policy Preferences -- I wish I could +1 more than once.